# How to use a bubbleplot in ggplot2/R to deal with overplotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot of categorical variables as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2CJF.png

This is a very small subset of the actual data (n > 10000)

While jittering handles the overplotting, it is ugly and can lead to ambiguity. I was keen to instead place bubbles to show the number of points that are co-incident.

I can't seem to find a simple and repeatable way to do this.

Thank you in advance!

Edit:

Thanks for the feedback. Here is what I hope is a reproducible example:

First, a CSV of the data (long, but relevant in this example):

```
ID,g,wf,fi
1824848,14,2,4
1314001,14,2,3
670960,14,1,3
1313235,15,3,4
1172304,3,5,4
1859973,15,1,3
1826951,14,1,4
1868238,15,1,2
1911869,15,1,4
1911861,15,1,2
926829,14,1,3
1609578,3,4,4
1306895,3,5,4
1199557,15,1,4
692849,10,3,4
1923352,3,5,4
1881724,4,4,4
1384603,3,5,4
1928829,15,1,4
493503,3,5,4
902650,15,1,3
1887582,6,4,4
1887584,3,5,4
1933992,13,1,4
635372,3,3,4
1892765,15,1,2
1934773,13,2,4
1892530,14,2,4
936786,3,5,4
1897585,13,3,4
1895932,15,1,3
422785,15,1,3
1219573,8,1,4
1897817,3,2,4
1899612,14,3,4
1939157,15,1,4
1952043,14,1,3
1938048,14,1,3
1896607,15,1,2
1941385,15,1,3
1959437,3,5,4
1064010,15,1,3
1951600,13,3,4
541439,15,1,4
1938609,3,5,4
1958667,15,1,2
1943792,10,1,4
1943782,14,1,4
1893714,14,1,4
1335502,15,1,1
1950179,3,2,4
1959069,15,1,2
1958811,15,1,2
1958808,15,3,4
1959878,15,1,1
1949904,15,1,3
1961475,15,1,4
1876863,15,1,4
384705,15,1,3
1966338,15,1,4
1980290,3,4,4
1966997,15,2,4
1967107,15,1,1
1976077,15,1,2
1967579,11,1,4
1967387,4,2,4
1973408,3,3,4
1684881,3,3,3
```

...and the plot code:

```
sx <- ggplot(dx, aes(x=fi, y=wf)) + 
    geom_point(shape=19, alpha=1, size=1, position=position_jitter(width=0.1,height=.1))
print(sx)
```

I really don't know where to go from here, other than manually making a count matrix...

Thanks again (sorry, new to stackoverflow).

Comment: I think you're looking for `stat_sum()`.

Comment: stat_sum() looks perfect - thanks!